# Is there a difference on how java performs operations using shortcut operators from the regular ones?

Tags: java, operators, operator-precedence

I am working on a java program concerning the pascal's triangle.

So this is how it is coded:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for(int j = 0, x = 1; j <= i; j++){
        System.out.print(x + " ");
        x = x * (i - j) / (j + 1);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

and it shows:

1 
1 1 
1 2 1 
1 3 3 1 
1 4 6 4 1

But when I tried to change the code to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for(int j = 0, x = 1; j <= i; j++){
        System.out.print(x + " ");
        x *= (i - j) / (j + 1);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

and as you may have noticed, only the operator has changed to *=, but the result is:

1 
1 1 
1 2 0 
1 3 3 0 
1 4 4 0 0

Any idea what must have happened? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because you're using integer arithmetic in the wrong order.

```
x *= (i - j) / (j + 1);
```

is the same as

```
x = x * ((i - j) / (j + 1));
```

The brackets are important.  `(i - j) / (j + 1)` is in most cases not a whole number, but java rounds it to an integer anyway.

The way you did it first

```
x = x * (i - j) / (j + 1);
```

the multiplication happens before the division, so you don't get any rounding errors.

Comment: Well, my bad. I actually wrote this code in javascript to reproduce the result, but it's ok with js. Now I know... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

You switched the high precedence * for a low precedence *= resulting in

```
x = x * ((i - j) / (j + 1));
```

in stead of

```
x = (x * (i - j)) / (j + 1);
```

which you probably wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like integer division versus order of operations. Try adding some parenthesis and I think you will eventually achieve the same results. If you, say, divide 2/3 in integers, you get 0. So it matters if you do some multiplying first.